# Two buttons to toggle between two functions and a single function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

There are 2 buttons and two functions.

Button1 should toggle between functionA and functionB.
Button2 should always trigger functionB only.

```
$("#hamburger").click( toggleAB );

$("#close").click(function(){
   functionB();
});

functionA(){ //expand menu }
functionB(){ //collapse menu }

function toggleAB(){
    var el = this;
    return [
      function() { functionA(); },
      function() { functionB(); }
    ][el.tog^=1]();
}
```

At the moment `$("#hamburger")` toggles perfectly between the two functions. But if I click the `$("#close")` button, then I have to click the `$("#hamburger")` button twice to continue toggling between the two functions.

My question is how do I make the `$("#hamburger")` to toggle between functionA and functionB even if the `$("#close")` button was clicked or not?

Comment: Woah... Why is that I feel the code is too complicated in the `[el.tog^=1]();` section?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks for the response. please suggest a simpler way to toggle between the two functions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to store a flag on the button so you can tell which function was called last, so you know which to call next. Try this:

```js
$("#hamburger").click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks') || 0;
  clicks % 2 == 0 ? functionA() : functionB();
  $(this).data('clicks', ++clicks);
});

$("#close").click(function() {
  functionB();
});

function functionA() {
  console.log('A');
}
function functionB() {
  console.log('B');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hamburger">Hamburger</button>
<button id="close">Close</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Does not work. I guess this is because  `var clicks = $(this).data('clicks') || 0;` is inside the `$("#hamburger")` click functon ?

Comment: It clearly works in the snippet I added above, so there may be an issue with your version. Check the console for errors elsewhere in your page

Comment: No, the scope of `clicks` is correct. It should be within the `#hamburger` click handler